# Can you fix the tool window width in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I am very happy to use PyCharm every day. I have many tool windows fixed to the left. When switching, for example from debugger to project overview, I am annoyed by the constantly changing width. I can correct it for each tab by dragging.

Can I sync the width to, for example, 300 px for all tabs so that you can still drag en resize but that it doesn't change when switching?

Comment: One of the best ways is pinning your debug window to the sidebar/bottom and setting it with right click as floating.

Comment: And then having 10 floating windows of somewhat equal size?

Comment: Right click on the border of the window, there are 2 options `View Mode` and `Move to`. After the debug window is pinned where you want, resize it to a fixed size by left-click&drag, that size will be kept (try the `dock pinned` option).

Comment: Yes, that works fine. That is not my question though. I want to have the width for all tool windows pinned to the left top to have the same width.